# equation of motion for the scalar field via variational principle in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, variational-principle

I would like to find the equation of motion for the scalar field $\phi$ by varying the following action in General Relativity.

Special Relativity:
$$
S = -\tfrac{1}{2}\int d^4\xi\, \eta^{ab} \partial_a \phi\partial_b\phi
$$

General Relativity:
$$
S = -\tfrac{1}{2}\int d^4x \sqrt{g}\, g^{\mu\nu} \partial_{\mu} \phi\partial_\nu \phi
$$

I was able to get the correct equation using the covariant derivatives. Since they are constant with respect to the metric partial integration works and one obtains $ \Box\phi = 0$. But since for the scalar field the covariant and the partial derivates are the same I wanted to vary the action with the partial derivatives.

Note: $\phi \rightarrow \phi + \delta\phi$
$$
\begin{align}
\delta S &=  -\tfrac{1}{2}\int d^4x \sqrt{g}\, (g^{\mu\nu} \partial_{\mu} \delta\phi\partial_\nu\phi + g^{\mu\nu} \partial_{\mu} \phi\partial_{\nu} \delta\phi )  \\
%
&=-\int d^4x \sqrt{g}\, g^{\mu\nu} \partial_{\mu} \delta\phi\partial_\nu\delta\phi \\
%
&=\int d^4x \, \partial_\nu(\sqrt{g}\,g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu\phi)\delta\phi
\end{align}
$$
The third line one obtains after partial integration. But at this point I'm stuck.
I know the following definition:
$$
\Box\phi = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{g}}\partial_\mu(\sqrt{g}g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\nu\phi)
$$
But I'm not able to convert my obtained solution into this. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: You already have your answer though. Given your result for $\delta S$, the equation you get is $\partial_\mu( \sqrt{g} g^{\mu\nu} \partial_\nu \phi) = 0$. This is the wave equation. Dividing by $\sqrt{g}$ (which can be done since the metric is positive-definite) and exchanging the indices $\mu$ and $\nu$ (note that the metric is symmetric), we produce $\Box \phi = 0$.

Comment: @Prahar Small comment: the metric of GR is not necessarily positive definite, it is however non-degenerate.